# sed / regex: splitting bigrams to new lines (multiple line input)

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to use sed to split a text into bigrams (sets of two adjacent words). I'm using the following command:

```
sed -r 's/(\\w+) (\\w+)/\\1 \\2\\n/g' input.txt >output.txt
```

The problem is that sed splits the input after every second word with a new line, and continues **after** that sequence (i.e. at the third word). I want it to take the second word as the next starting point.

Example:

```
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
the squirrel ate my homework
```

results in:

```
the quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy
the squirrel
ate my
```

What I want is:

```
the quick
quick brown
brown fox
fox jumped
jumped over
over the
the lazy
lazy dog
the squirrel
squirrel ate
ate my
my homework
```

I guess I could run another sed command by deleting the first word of the original input. But is there a way to get the desired result in one command?

Comment: The use of double-backslashes inside single quotes is peculiar.  What OS and command shell are you using?

Comment: If your input can have multiple lines, you should edit your question to show that and the associated desired output.

Comment: @John1024: I'm calling sed from R via the system() command. The complete command is: system("sed -r 's/(\\w+) (\\w+)/\\1 \\2\\n/g' input.txt >output.txt"). OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @EdMorton: Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple and just use awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i, $(i+1)}' file
the quick
quick brown
brown fox
fox jumped
jumped over
over the
the lazy
lazy dog
the squirrel
squirrel ate
ate my
my homework
```

Clear, simple, obvious, brief, robust, portable, efficient, etc., etc....

I see you were asking about trigrams in a comment, the tweak to the above is just the obvious:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<(NF-1);i++) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}' file
the quick brown
quick brown fox
brown fox jumped
fox jumped over
jumped over the
over the lazy
the lazy dog
the squirrel ate
squirrel ate my
ate my homework
```

Comment: Looks intriguingly simple. Could you elaborate on the way it works? Does $i stand for a word, a character, a line? With "file" you mean the input file I suppose?

Comment: I edited my answer to show the script running against your new multi-line input. As it reads lines, awk separates every line into space-separated fields numbered 1 through NF (Number of Fields) so in the above `i` is the field number in the current lin and `$i` is the field (word in your case) at that position. Yes "file" is the input file. If you might do any more text manipulation, get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as awk is THE standard UNIX tool for manipulating text. P.S. awk operates on lines by default but it operates on any blocks of text (Records).

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/ /  /g; s/ (\w+) / \1\n\1/g; s/  / /' input.txt
the quick
quick brown
brown fox
fox jumped
jumped over
over the
the lazy
lazy dog
the squirrel
squirrel ate
ate my
my homework
```

The above was tested with GNU sed on Linux.  On BSD (Mac OSX), try:

```
sed -r -e 's/ /  /g' -e 's/ (\w+) / \1\n\1/g' -e 's/  / /' input.txt
```

#### How it works

- `s/ /  /g`

  This doubles up on the spaces so that the command which follows works properly.
- `s/ (\w+) / \1\n\1/g`

  This takes every word and doubles: the single word is replaced by a copy of the word, followed by a newline, followed by another copy of the word.
- `s/  / /`

  This removes a superfluous space from the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' | \
  sed ': X; s/\(\w\+\) \(\w\+\) \(\w\+\)/\1 \2\n\2 \3/; t X'
the quick
quick brown
brown fox
fox jumped
jumped over
over the
the lazy
lazy dog
```

As explained in https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands, `: X` declares a label `X`. `t X` jumps back to `X` if the preceding substitution was successful. That is, we loop as long as the regex keeps matching. This is almost like `s///g`; the difference is that `s///g` won't rescan the part it substituted for more matches, but this program will.

Comment: What does the ": X;" and the "; t X" stand for?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+) /\1\n&/2g' file
```

Replaces from the second symbol; the symbol followed by a space by the symbol followed by a newline followed by the complete match globaly throughout the line.

Another method is:

```
sed -r 's/^\S+ (\S+)/&\n\1/;//P;D' file
```

This method can be extended for trigrams to:

```
sed -r 's/^\S+ (\S+ \S+)/&\n\1/;//P;D' file
```

Comment: Thank you, this is quite fast. How would I extend this to trigrams? e.g.

the quick brown/
quick brown fox/
brown fox jumps/
fox jumps over/
...

I tried "sed -r 's/(\S+ \S+) /\1\n&/2g' file", but this gives me 4-grams with combinations missing.